Why is executing JUnit tests in IntelliJ not working as advertised?
In IntelliJ, how can I run all of the tests in a particular class that do not have a specific tag associated with them?
I am running the most recent version of IntelliJ, 2024.2 Ultimate Edition. If I create a new run configuation by selecting "Edit Configurations..." and then clicking the "+" and selecting "Junit" as the test type, the dialog that shows up is not at all specific to JUnit.  In Stack Overflow posts, I see that there can be a "Tags" option there. This is the first troubling sign. Should the dialog that appears have some JUnit specific fields?
I have my tests methods annotated with @Test. Tests I want to exclude are also annotated with @Tag("ohio"). I want to run all of the tests in a particular class that don't have the specific tag "ohio" annotated on the method. I've tried three ways of getting this behavior by editing the "Run Configuration" that will be used to run the tests.  But whatever I try here doesn't work:

I've seen some docs that indicate that there should be some options in the dialog that let me specify a tag.  But these fields don't show up for me in the dialog:


I can select "Tags" instead of "Class", and indicate filtering out the tags I want excluded with "!ohio". But this causes all tests in all of my classes to run. The run is no longer limited to just the one class, as makes sense because this "Tags" option replaces the "Class" option in the dialog:


I have tried adding the commmand line option -DexcludeTags=ohio to get the behavior I want. When I run with this option, it seems to be ignored. The tests that it should exclude still run:




I don't think it's advertised anywhere but there is indeed a long-standing feature request to have a more flexible run configuration. I can see quite a number of related tickets on their YouTrack have been closed for various reasons.
The only ticket which is linked to the closed ones and still open is https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-153780/Add-support-for-JUnit-categories-equivalent-to-that-provided-by-Maven-surefire-failsafe-plugins. Even though it says Maven you can still see some comments where people demand more flexibility and in the linked issues there are closed IDEA-256621 and IDEA-245281 asking about "Running all tests in a folder && without a certain Tag". There is also this SO question asking the same and leading to one of the tickets mentioned.
Also, I don't think the -DexcludeTags option exists and not sure if IntelliJ runner can be customised in some way to support your custom properties and propagate it in the form supported by JUnit like you can see at https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-console-launcher-options (see -T, --exclude-tag=TAG).
I know it's frustrating but looks like our best bet is to keep asking JetBrains to enhance their run configuration or help them do it.
